How to use a Mule payload to structure an HTML for email body purpose?
We have a payload as below:
{
  "API1": "UP",
  "API2": "DOWN",
  "API3": "UP"
}

We need to structure this in HTML and read(using parse template) to send it in email body as Table with 2 columns and 'n' rows.
We cannot hardcode this payload, it needs to be dynamic and read as payload in the flow because there might be 'n' number of APIs.
How to read payload in the template using HTML, CSS and/or JS?
The payload will be json object as mentioned above:
We need table in below format and dynamic to include 'n' rows:
API Names | API Statuses
-------------------------
API1      | UP
API2      | UP
API3      | DOWN


This question is similar to: JSON array to Table structure formatting while sending email via Mule 4. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Karthik Edited

This helped with few tweaks. Thank you

Add this JS code to your HTML file internally or externally.
At first tableBody.innerHTML = ''; will clear Table Body then will add your payload to the table dynamically.
    <script>
        const payload = {
            "API1": "UP",
            "API2": "DOWN",
            "API3": "UP"
        };

        function genTableRows(payload) {
            const tableBody = document.querySelector('#apiTable tbody');
            tableBody.innerHTML = '';

            for (const [api, status] of Object.entries(payload)) {
                const row = document.createElement('tr');
                const cell1 = document.createElement('td');
                const cell2 = document.createElement('td');

                cell1.textContent = api;
                cell2.textContent = status;

                row.appendChild(cell1);
                row.appendChild(cell2);
                tableBody.appendChild(row);
            }
        }
        genTableRows(payload);
    </script>


The code you've provided has payload constant. I need it to be dynamic, reading from Mule flow.
